# Setting cmake variable in command line and comparing it with string

Tags: cmake

I'm calling my CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
cmake   ../.. -DTARGET=JETSON_NANO
```

Then, this line:

```
message(STATUS "------------ TARGET: ${TARGET}")
```

prints `------------ TARGET: JETSON_NANO`

but this line:

```
if (TARGET STREQUAL JETSON_NANO)
```

gives error:

```
if given arguments:

    "TARGET" "STREQUAL" "JETSON_NANO"
```

Why? `TARGET` is setted!

Comment: Note, that when use string literal with `STREQUAL` or some other `if` construction, it is better to enclose this literal with double quotes: `"JETSON_NANO"`. Otherwise, if the variable with given name exists, CMake will substitute value of the variable instead of the literal. This is, however, unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TARGET` is a special **keyword** for `if` command. It is used for check whether given *target* (in CMake sense) exists. Correct usage of this keyword includes **two arguments** of `if`:

```
if(TARGET JETSON_NANO) # Checks whether CMake target JETSON_NANO exists
```

This is why CMake emits error when you use this keyword with three arguments:

```
if (TARGET STREQUAL "JETSON_NANO") # Error: 'TARGET' keyword requires two `if` arguments
```

However, you may **swap** compared strings in `if` command:

```
if ("JETSON_NANO" STREQUAL TARGET) # Compares string "JETSON_NANO" with variable TARGET
```

See more about `if` command in its [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/if.html).